# Duplicate key in for loop terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create cloudwatch dashboards for ALB with multiple ALB and Target groups.
But I am getting an error while passing same value to the for loop "AWS/ApplicationELB" so is there any by which I can remove this duplicate in for loop.

data.tf

```
dashboards = [
  {
    my-dashboard-name = "Cloudwatch-Dashboard-ALB-test3"
    aws-region        = "us-east-1"
    targets           = ["app/test3/e8586bb7d49cf35b"]
    target_groups     = ["targetgroup/test-tg-2/f2e0260797ce83e8","targetgroup/test4/2dd3e8ae3bf2cb94"]
    metrics           = ["RequestCountPerTarget", "NewConnectionCount", "TargetResponseTime", "HTTPCode_Target_2XX_Count","RuleEvaluations", "HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count", "HTTPCode_Target_3XX_Count", "HTTP_Redirect_Count", "ActiveConnectionCount", "ProcessedBytes", "HTTPCode_ELB_3XX_Count", "RequestCount", "HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count", "HTTPCode_ELB_504_Count", "ConsumedLCUs", "HTTPCode_ELB_503_Count", "HTTPCode_ELB_502_Count", "HTTP_Fixed_Response_Count", "HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count", "UnHealthyHostCount", "HealthyHostCount"]
    aws-namespace     = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
    dim               = "LoadBalancer"
    service_names      = ""
    stat              = "Average"
    period            = 300
  },
  {
     my-dashboard-name = "Cloudwatch-Dashboard-ALB-test"
     aws-region        = "us-east-1"
     targets           = ["app/test2/eb397187e673ccc3"]
     target_groups     = ["targetgroup/test-tg/62fdb81766299e0e"]
     metrics           = ["RequestCountPerTarget", "NewConnectionCount", "TargetResponseTime", "HTTPCode_Target_2XX_Count","RuleEvaluations", "HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count", "HTTPCode_Target_3XX_Count", "HTTP_Redirect_Count", "ActiveConnectionCount", "ProcessedBytes", "HTTPCode_ELB_3XX_Count", "RequestCount", "HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count", "HTTPCode_ELB_504_Count", "ConsumedLCUs", "HTTPCode_ELB_503_Count", "HTTPCode_ELB_502_Count", "HTTP_Fixed_Response_Count", "HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count", "UnHealthyHostCount", "HealthyHostCount"]
     aws-namespace     = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
     dim               = "LoadBalancer"
     service_names      = ""
     stat              = "Average"
     period            = 300
   },
 ]
}
```

cloudwatch.tf

```
module "create-dashboard" {
  source = "../"
  for_each       = { for service in local.dashboards : service.aws-namespace  => service}
  dashboard-name = each.value.my-dashboard-name
  aws-region     = each.value.aws-region
  targets        = each.value.targets
  metrics        = each.value.metrics
  aws-namespace  = each.value.aws-namespace
  dim            = each.value.dim
  service_names  = each.value.service_names
  target_groups  = each.value.target_groups
  cluster_name   = ["a-cluster"]
  stat           = each.value.stat
  period         = each.value.period
}
```

Error

```
╷
│ Error: Duplicate object key
│
│   on cloudwatch-v1.tf line 10, in module "create-dashboard":
│   10:   for_each       = { for idx, service in local.dashboards : service.aws-namespace  => service}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ service.aws-namespace is "AWS/ApplicationELB"
│
│ Two different items produced the key "AWS/ApplicationELB" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value
│ expression to enable grouping by key
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more transparent for your config and state if the module declared name key was synced with the `my-dashboard-name` object key, and that would also fix your issue:

```
module "create-dashboard" {
  source   = "../"
  for_each = { for service in local.dashboards : service.my-dashboard-name  => service}
  ...
}
```